# multiple selects from a function into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, temp-tables, sql-function

- I have a function helper_function which I want to reuse
- Passing a parameter to another function f_union_helper_functions where a string id_string with ids is passed
- Split this string and iterate through all ids
- calling the function and adding result to a temp table
- return select from this table

Pseudo code:

```
create function f_union_helper_functions
(
@id_string varchar,
...
return table as
return
(
...
foreach id in @id_string
begin
   select * from helper_function(id) into #tmp
end
select #tmp
)
```

This code above is far from being complete/correct. I just want to combine the concepts of iterating and union into a temp table and return it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: use a table value parameter instead?

Comment: Using `cross apply`. `SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@id_string, ',') c cross apply helper_function(c.value)`. You won't need the `STRING_SPLIT` function as you've already figured that out.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: And also, *I just want to combine the concepts of iterating and union into a temp table and return it.* -- what are you actually trying to achieve here?  This smells like very poor database design.

Comment: @Ajay Gupta Thx for this great answer; only problem is that we use SQL2008 and i cant use STRING_SPLIT therefor

Comment: @iamdrive SQL-Server 2008; I dont want to change the relativly long function therefore thats the way to join tables; ids shouldnt be too many 
Performance is not a big issue there;

Comment: Well, you can use a UDF for splitting the string

Comment: Thank you very much for all answers; Thx @Ajay Gupta for the hint with the cross apply!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I solved it:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_union_helper_functions]
(
    @id_string NVARCHAR(1024)
)
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
(
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@id_string, ',') c CROSS APPLY [dbo].[helper_function](c.item)
)
```

If you got SQLServer >= 2016 you can use STRING_SPLIT instead of [fnSplit], which I got from here https://kishsharma.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/sql-server-user-defined-function-to-split-the-string-by-special-char/